# Ubuntu goes to sleep, runs out of battery, then completely freezes when waking up

Tags: suspend, shutdown, battery

> I am running Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid). If any system specs are needed I will try my best to provide these.

So, I have the (bad) habit of falling asleep while looking at cartoons.

I unplug the power supply to the laptop and move it to my bedroom. The problem is, that it usually runs out of power completely (sometimes after going to sleep, sometimes without it) and when I plug it back in it seems to be stuck on an empty X Window instance (similar to what you get when you press Alt+Ctrl+F8), the underscore doesn't blink, instead it's stuck.

If I try Alt+Left to switch to another X Window, it doesn't work, neither does Alt+Ctrl+any function button.

Usually I shut it down from the button at this point because it's totally unresponsive.

1.) Is there any danger for my PC as a result of my actions?

2.) Is there any way to avoid this issue

3.) If this issue pops up again, is there any way to solve it cleanly, without powering down?

Answer (score 0):

It can't still be powered on if it ran out of battery [ubuntu would not be on the screen. It would be pure black darkness]; If it ran out of battery it would be booting back up into ubuntu after you turned it back on after you plugged it in.

...So that makes no sense at all. Apparently, it can't be out of battery and is just in a frozen state. Why its freezing is something else and you would need to learn what's causing it to learn how to fix it.

At least on mine, when it runs critically low on battery Ubuntu shutsdown automatically. Then it needs to be turned on again. There's nothing unsafe about that.

As long as the hard drive isn't active, the head is parked, it shouldn't hurt it. Everything else really is motionless. I have no problem with forcing a locked pc or laptop down if its necessary cause what else to do? Throw it? [could always do that :-) ]

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it shuts down right, but sometimes when I try to start it back up it will try to open the site again with the video player in Fullscreen and that will be pretty slow, but other times it straight up freezes as described above.